# How to get values if JSON Array elements in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I've an JSON Array in PHP which has two elements.
Now I want to get values of each element separately to store in Db.
My JSON Array is As follow:

```
{"NetStock":[{"Phy_Stock1":"4","Sys_Stock1":"5"},{"Phy_Stock2":"3","Sys_Stock2":"4"}]}
```

Now I want to get values of each Phy_Stock and Sys_Stock separately.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ie=UTF-8&q=How%20to%20get%20values%20if%20JSON%20Array%20elements%20in%20PHP

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$json_value = '{"NetStock":[{"Phy_Stock1":"4","Sys_Stock1":"5"},{"Phy_Stock2":"3","Sys_Stock2":"4"}]}';

$data = json_decode($json_value, true);

echo "PHP Array</br>";
print_r($data);

echo "</br></br>";
echo 'value of phy_stock1 : ' . $data['NetStock'][0]['Phy_Stock1'];
```

// Output

```
PHP Array
Array ( [NetStock] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [Phy_Stock1] => 4 [Sys_Stock1] => 5 ) [1] => Array ( [Phy_Stock2] => 3 [Sys_Stock2] => 4 ) ) )

value of phy_stock1 : 4
```

Comment: Thanks Bro! As I'm a beginner in PHP Plz guide me how to iterate through Whole this array.

Comment: @gulbazkhan Since the array values are different (Phy_Stock1, Sys_Stock1, Phy_Stock2, Sys_Stock2), It is difficult to iterate.

Answer (score 0):

```
$json_value = '{"NetStock":[{"Phy_Stock1":"4","Sys_Stock1":"5"},{"Phy_Stock2":"3","Sys_Stock2":"4"}]}';

$data = json_decode($json_value, true);//assoc array

$option1 = $data['NetStock'][0]['Phy_Stock1'];//4

$option2 = $data['NetStock'][0]['Sys_Stock1'];//5
```

Answer (score 0):

The Below code will give the details

```
<?php
    $json_array = '{"NetStock":[{"Phy_Stock1":"4","Sys_Stock1":"5"},{"Phy_Stock2":"3","Sys_Stock2":"4"}]}';

    $json_details = json_decode($json_array, true); //assoc array

    $Phy_Stock1 = $json_details['NetStock'][0]['Phy_Stock1'];
    echo $Phy_Stock1."<br>";

    $Sys_Stock1 = $json_details['NetStock'][0]['Sys_Stock1'];
    echo $Sys_Stock1."<br>";

    $Phy_Stock2 = $json_details['NetStock'][1]['Phy_Stock2'];
    echo $Phy_Stock2."<br>";

    $Sys_Stock2 = $json_details['NetStock'][1]['Sys_Stock2'];
    echo $Sys_Stock2."<br>";
?>
```